# Windows Powershell and concatenation?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, concatenation, ps

I'm looking at adding up the capacity of all disks on localhost machine using a ForEach-Object. I'm able to get the size listed but it lists them separately. How can I combine the size of multiple disks to display as one calculation?

Here is what I have so far:

$drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicalDisk

$drivecap = ($drives | ForEach-Object {$_.Size/1GB})

"The Total Capacity of all fixed drives: $drivecap GB" | out-file -FilePath $myfile -append

I'm looking to achieve something like "The Total Capacity of all fixed drives: 800.99000000001 GB"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will help you to get the total disk space from the localhost.

```
$drives = Get-WmiObject Win32_logicalDisk
$total = 0
foreach($drive in $drives) {
$total += $drive.Size/1GB
}
Write-Host "The Total Capacity of all fixed drives:"$total
```

Comment: If it is helpful, could you please make it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```bsh
$drivecap = ($drives | measure -Property Size -Sum | select -Expand Sum) / 1GB
```

another alternative:

```bsh
$drivecap = $drives |% {$x=0} {$x += $_.Size/1GB} {$x}
```